# What MySQL column type should I use to store Integers of 13 digits?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to store integers with 13 length, but I don't want any complications.

Things to consider:

- be indexable, sortable (just like a normal Int column)
- shouldn't have any special "padding".  I heard that sometimes BigInt pads zeros to the left of the number. I don't want to manually trim the zeros every time I query a database.

This may sound dumb - but basically, I just want an Integer column that can hold 13 digits.

What column type should I go with?

Comment: Padding is optional for all integer types, based on whether the [`ZEROFILL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) attribute is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use bigint

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

```
Type      | Storage | Minimum Value        | Maximum Value
          | (Bytes) | (Signed/Unsigned)    | (Signed/Unsigned)
----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------
TINYINT   | 1       | -128                 | 127
          |         | 0                    | 255
----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------
SMALLINT  | 2       | -32768               | 32767
          |         | 0                    | 65535
----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------
MEDIUMINT | 3       | -8388608             | 8388607
          |         | 0                    | 16777215
----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------
INT       | 4       | -2147483648          | 2147483647
          |         | 0                    | 4294967295
----------+---------+----------------------+----------------------
BIGINT    | 8       | -9223372036854775808 | 9223372036854775807
          |         | 0                    | 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're searching for [decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

In your specific case, a Decimal(13, 0).

Decimals are stored in packed binary, semantics (sorts) being those of integers. They're typically nicer than "float" in some contexts because you're not storing a base 2 mantissa and exponent, but a decimal (base 10) "integer part" and "fractional part" so you're not getting weird roundings typical of float. But that's not your question, just saying.

Comment: What's interesting about using `DECIMAL(13,0)` is that it uses only 6-bytes whereas `BIGINT` uses 8.  So it's certainly an interesting approach for the very storage conscious—though IMHO the advantages of faster integer arithmetic etc might well outweigh those savings in many applications: it really depends on what one needs to do with the data.